# LibreOffice Calc | How to reference a column (to iterate all rows) using a formula in "Find & Replace"?

Tags: worksheet-function, find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc

i have two columns: A and B. In column A, there is some currency values (all positives). In column B, there is a value that indicates if column A value is positive or negative.

i was reading the help and find this: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Assigning_Formats_by_Formula

Is possible to write a formula in "Replace" to change the value of column A (-1*value_column_A) if the respective value (same row) in column B?

I tried this: 
Into "Find"   : .*

Into "Replace": =IF(B2="S";-1*&;&)

This works partially: the formula use the value from B2 (dont iterate the row) to change the value from all A rows.
I can't find how to write B reference to iterate to all rows.

(I know that is possible to solve this using other methods but I am curious if this is possible to do in that way - using "Find & Replace").

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT).  Here is the formula for the *Replace* field.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("B"\&ROW())="S";-1*&;&)
```

The result, starting with 1 through 5 in column A.

[image: columns where B = S are negative]

After using this type of forumla the first time, it can be repeated by selecting *Edit -> Find and Replace -> Other Options -> Search in -> Values*.